# compile libstdc++ against musl

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++, musl

I have to compile some c++ programs with musl-gcc wrapper and so i need c++ headers and libs. Before i can i use them, i guess that i have to compile the libstdc++ source against musl, with musl-gcc itself.

I got the libstdc++ source from the latest version of gcc source and, according to [this guide](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/systemd/chapter05/gcc-libstdc++.html) all i have to do is to run configure specifing the compiler path (that is /usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc) as the --host option argument

However, the configure fails and i get the error

```
cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "../<folder name>/libstdc++-v3" "../<folder name>/libstdc++-v3/.." "../<folder name>/libstdc++-v3/../.."
```

Am I missing some step?

Answer (score 2):

`libstdc++` can only be built as a part of `gcc` distribution, it can't be built standalone. So, at first, you need full gcc source distribution.

When you get it, you still will not be able to build libstdc++ simply as `./configure --host=...`. It is closely tied with gcc itself; you will have to adjust configure args and modify configure scripts (at least `acinclude.m4`, `configure.ac`).

Enjoy